# JavaScript: define a function of a function result

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I'm attempting to build a binding handler for knockout (using knockout-es5), and would like to bind a function defined in the viewModel to the init function's value Accessor so the viewModel can trigger a callback from the binding handler.

Effectively, I have a function (valueAccessor()) that returns a function, that I would like to define in the handler. Unfortunately, I find myself attempting to do:

```
valueAccessor() = function() { //stuff }
```

This returns an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

However, I *can* do something like this:

(In ViewModel.ts, in typescript)

```
class ViewModel {
    handlerObj: { trigger: () => void } = {} as any;
    // (further down)
        handlerObj.trigger();
}
```

(In template)

```
<div data-bind="triggered: handlerObj"></div>
```

(in bindingHandler.js, in javascript)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.triggered = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var block = $(element);
        valueAccessor().trigger = function () {
            // action to be triggered
        };
    }
}
```

The question I have is: can this be done without the intervening 'handlerObj' object?

Comment: to fix an error just go with `var valueAccessor = function() { /*stuff*/ }`

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample illustrating the problem? Your code works ok for me - https://jsfiddle.net/uev6bLxd/2/

Comment: @AlekseyL. I tried that. Unfortunately, this just affects valueAccessor, and not the underlying return function, which is what the viewModel itself will call,

Comment: @TSV Indeed, the code I posted here was my work around, which as I said does work. I'm looking for a solution (if one exists) where handlerObj is not needed: i.e, trigger is defined directly in the ViewModel.
i.e., https://jsfiddle.net/49hvhsh7/